# Javascript - Call map in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am creating a phonegap application for android.  I am not really familiar with Javascript and have encountered a scenario where I have two functions, one which initialises a map called "map" and another which takes care of showing a list of markers which is being loaded from a database on the map.

However my question is how am I able to set the marker to appear on a map which is initiated in a different function?

EDIT
Here is some code:

function map() {
...
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
...
}

`function markers() {
var MarkerType1 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/android_asset/www/assets/markerType1.png",
        new google.maps.Size(29.0, 48.0),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(14.0, 24.0)
    );`

var MarkerType2 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/android_asset/www/assets/markerType2.png",
        new google.maps.Size(29.0, 48.0),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(14.0, 24.0)
    );

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var eventList = $('ul#eventList').empty();

```
var eventPoints = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.somedomain.com/loadEvents.php?&jsoncallback=?',
    dataType: 'JSONp',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            if (item.EventType == 1) {                  
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude),
                        map: this.map,
                        icon: MarkerType1,
                        draggable:false
                    });                      

            } else if (item.EventType == 2) {
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude),
                    map: this.map,
                    icon: MarkerType2,
                    draggable:false
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of variable scope. Make sure the variable `map` is declared outside both of the functions.

eg. :

```
$(function() {
    var map;//outer variable is accessible within both functions.

    function createMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map({
            ...
        });
    }

    function createMarkers() {
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function() {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        ...
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }

    createMap();
    createMarkers();

});
```

In practice, you would only need to put the map/marker creation code inside functions if it needed to be called in response to some future event(s).

If you want to create the map and its markers immediately, when page is loaded, then you can do so as follows :

```
$(function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map({
        ...
    });

    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function() {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    ...
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is somewhat similar to my setup.  Now when the user navigates to that page, I am calling the createMap() function.  But how would I call the createMarkers then?

Comment: This is another scope issue. Functions are subject to scope in exactly the same way as other variables/objects. As the two functions, `createMap()` and `createMarkers()`, are inside a `$(function(){...})` structure, they are only accessible within that structure. With jQuery it's not uncommon for all of your code to be in a single `$(function(){...})` structure.

Comment: See additional text in answer above.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of handling this off the top of my head. One solution is to go up the scope chain until both both the marker scope and the map scope are descendants of the current scope, then instantiate variables, as such

```
   var map;
   var markers;
```

Then in these functions bind the generated objects to those variables. This way both will be able to access the other through these variables.

Another method would be to use an observer pattern ([several alternatives here](http://jsperf.com/pubsubjs-vs-jquery-custom-events/50)) to publish the map and markers as they are ready, and have subscribers in either one (as you see fit) to listen for the other's readiness and capture the passed object.

The difference being that method 1 exposes the map and markers to all other descendant scopes (may not be desirable).